# React-Bootstrap. Specifically with Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, react-native, bootstrap-4

So I have a parsing error and i don't know how to fix it.
I am using React Bootstrap and I'm having trouble with declaring the Components at the very top of my code. And I just copied the Carousel code from the React-Bootstrap website itself and I just wanted to run it locally but I cannot seem to fix this issue.

Line 4:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

```
        2 | import logo from './logo.svg';
        3 | import './App.css';
   >    4 | import { Carousel, Carousel.Item, Carousel.Caption } from 'react-bootstrap';
          |                            ^
        5 | 
        6 | class App extends Component {
        7 |   render() {
```

My full code is here:

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';
     import logo from './logo.svg';
     import './App.css';
     import { Carousel, Carousel.Item, Carousel.Caption } from 'react-bootstrap';

     class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
           <header className="App-header">
           {/* <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
           {<p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p> */}
            <Carousel>
               <Carousel.Item>
                 <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/carousel.png" />
                 <Carousel.Caption>
                   <h3>First slide label</h3>
                      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                 </Carousel.Caption>
               </Carousel.Item>
               <Carousel.Item>
                 <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/carousel.png" />
                  <Carousel.Caption>
                     <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                  </Carousel.Caption>
               </Carousel.Item>
               <Carousel.Item>
                 <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src="/carousel.png" />
                  <Carousel.Caption>
                    <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                         <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                  </Carousel.Caption>
               </Carousel.Item>
          </Carousel>;
          <a
        className="App-link"
        href="https://reactjs.org"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
        </a>
       </header>
      </div>
     );
  }
 }

 export default App;
```

Comment: You can't have periods in import statements. I'm assuming all you need to import is `Carousel` and it's children will come with.

Answer (score 1):

> 4 | import { Carousel, Carousel.Item, Carousel.Caption } from 'react-bootstrap';

You only need to import `Carousel`. That will automatically import `Carousel.Item` and `Carousel.Caption`, since `Item` and `Caption` are on the object `Carousel`.

Comment: Thanks! So i did what you said but it doesn't properly display as I wanted it to. For example, instead of having the carousel effect, it displays each picture and corresponding text one on top of each other. So if you know how to fix that as well, it would be very much appreciated!! ;)

Comment: I think that's a different issue, maybe you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: Ok I literally just did! If you can help me with this issue, that would be great! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959123/react-bootstrap-how-to-make-the-uncontrolled-carousel-component-work